# Motor feedback Control

Tags: operational-amplifier, motor, motor-controller

## Problem

Ok, so I'm a bit new to EE, but I've gotta run a 12v brushed DC motor run at a fairly consistent rate.

## Parts

I've selected Pololu's Jrk G2 for the job. https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73

And this is the feedback device: https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/ECHMP804

## Background

It seems like the pick up outputs a sine wave of about 2v @ 800hz at the slowest speed and 12v @ 2.8khz at full speed.

[image]

My initial thought was to rectify this, smooth it with a capacitor, and add a resistor to speed up the drain of the capacitor. Then use this analog DC signal for feedback with [this](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/5.2) configuration. I've built this and it works reasonably well, but I've since realized the temperature effects on a capacitor and am wondering if this is the wrong way to do this.

## Question

Is using a rectified AC signal as an analog input the right way to go, or should I find some way to use the AC signal with [this](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/5.3) configuration. I was thinking there might be a way to use an op amp to convert the 12v sine wave to a 5v square wave, but like I said, I'm a bit new to this.

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: A comparator would be an easy route to a 5 V square wave.